# Do I need Team foundation server in order to use CodedUI?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, coded-ui-tests

I'd like to write some basic tests for our web and Winforms applications.

I already own Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. Do I also need TFS in order to use the new CodedUI tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to have TFS in order to use Coded UI tests. You can create your tests in Visual Studio and run them direct from there, or via mstest. The main benefit TFS will add is the ability to execute tests across multiple physical and virtual tests machines via Test Manager. You will also get central collation of test results in the TFS repository.

Comment: How do you edit tests after you have created them? Changing UIMap.uitest by hand is a nightmare there seems to be no ide support in Visual Studio for that.

Comment: You edit tests with the Coded UI Test Builder in Visual Studio, you dont have to edit the .uitest file by hand. Check out the Hands-On Lab 'Introduction to Coded UI Tests with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate'. Its included with the VS2010 RC VM (http://blogs.msdn.com/briankel/archive/2010/03/18/now-available-visual-studio-2010-release-candidate-virtual-machines-with-sample-data-and-hands-on-labs.aspx).

Comment: This is a good resource for all-things Coded UI: http://blogs.msdn.com/mathew_aniyan/pages/content-index-for-coded-ui-test.aspx

Comment: You might want to check out CUITe It provides a great alternative to UIMaps. http://cuite.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need TFS. Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate is quite enough to record and launch codedUI tests.

Comment: Or Premium from 2012 onwards.